# Selected Row highlight not moving when gridview is sorted

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have an ASP.net gridview on a webform where user's can select a row.  When they select it, the row is highlighted yellow.  The problem is that when I sort the table, it sorts properly but the highlight stays on the same line.  The data all moves, but the highlight stays put.

Can anyone suggest how I can make the highlight stay with the data?

Comment: Check this link:  Read Mark Rideout's Post and see if that works for you : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/01f937af-d0d0-4de5-8919-088e88c5af77/

Comment: I don't think this is exactly what I need.  But it does suggest a basic framework: grab the tables datakeyvalue before the sort, then let the sort happen, reassign the selectedrowindex to that key, then rehighlight.  The problem is how to assign the correct index afterwards without looping.

Comment: Is there a way I can find the index of a particular datakeyvalue????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grab the SelectedDataKey.Value before the sort (OnSorting?).
Then after the sort (OnSorted?), use something like:

```
foreach(var row in GridView1.Rows)
{
   var i = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["MySavedSelectedDataKey"]));
   if(GridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value == i)
   {
       GridView1.SelectedIndex = row.RowIndex;
       break;
   }
}
```

You might need to call DataBind() again to show the new set SelectedIndex.

I don't believe there is anyway to do this without looping through each row. But if you have paging then you only have to loop through the number of rows in your PageSize property and not every single row returned from the database.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are sorting the data source for the grid, not the grid.

Get the id of the selected row before sorting, then set it as selected after sorting.

Comment: Problem is, that data is now in a different index after the sort.  I need to find and set that new index.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple to find currently selected item datakey - MyGrid.SelectedDataKey.Value.ToString()
That's if you have a single DataKey, otherwise you have to read both values, which are available under MyGrid.SelectedDataKey.Values

After sort you have to iterate over items and find the one with matching data keys. MyGrid.Rows[i].DataItem should help with that - note that this is only available when databinding, so if you re-sort without re-databinding (for example if you store all data in viewstate) it won't contain anything.

Comment: I got that first part no problem.  But how do I use .DataItem to look at cell values???

Comment: note that there's a difference between cell values and data source item values. you can access cell values no problem - just Rows[].Cells[].Controls[] collection. But these will be formatted. Much better to access DataItem - it actually contains DataRow or similar type (determined in debugger) and you can read the actual values that this row was databound to.